# HOW TO REMOVE INBUILT CALL RECORDER

Tags: root-access

I have I ball andi 3.5 kke winner, andriod 4.2.2. I want to remove inbuilt call recorder permanently. There is a logo "REC" on calling screen, showing recording time.

I have rooted my phone and tried Titanium Backup , Rom Toolbox Lite , Simple Root Uninstaller , SD Maid ,there is no apps having word "Call apps" etc.

Any idea to remove/uninstall inbuilt call recorder permanently ?

Thanks !